# Animation to move view with 200dp upside/downside

Tags: android, animation

I want to make animation to move layout exactly 200 dp up for android application. So far I tryed many ways and cannot make it to work on multiple screen sizes.

This is xml file that im using:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:duration="10000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-400" />


</set>
```

I tried this also

```
final TranslateAnimation moveUpAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, dpAsPixels, 0);
        dissapearAnnimation.setDuration(20000);
```

The problem is that this layout has dinamic content so its lenght is changing, so % of its lenght to move up is not working for me . Thanks in advancce !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`ViewPropertyAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html).

```
yourView.animate().translateY(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.animationHeight)).setDuration(yourDurationInMs);
```

In your dimension resources:

```
<dimen name="animationHeight">-200dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of layout are you using? To animation you sholdu use relative / frame layouts.

Comment: Im using linear layout